# Не могу настроить NGINX: no resolver defined to resolve backend

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

Что-то не получается разобраться в NGINX конфиге. До этого с настройкой не сталкивался вообще. В конфиге написано то, что ниже:

```
env BACKEND_API;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes 4;
events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
   http {
      include mime.types;
      default_type application/octet-stream;
      upstream backend {
         server backend;
      }
   server {
       set_by_lua $backend_url 'return os.getenv("BACKEND_API")';
       listen 80;
       server_name _;
       server_tokens off;
       client_max_body_size 100M; 

       location / {
           root   /www/html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }

       location /api {
           try_files $uri @proxy_api;
       }

       location @proxy_api {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_pass $backend_url;   
       } 
   }
  }
```

При попытке залогиниться на сайте, получаю 502 ошибку (да и в принципе при любом запросе):

```
frontend        | 2022/02/21 08:29:58 [error] 28#28: *2 no resolver defined to resolve backend, client: 31.176.83.92, server: _, request: "POST /api/auth HTTP/1.1", host: "194.86.154.183", referrer: "http://194.86.154.183/"
```

Изменения в конфиге адресов на 127.0.0.1 при попытке захардкодить тоже ни к чему меня не приводят.

Любая помощь и совет приветствуется, мои теоретические знаний по этой теме на данный момент скудны.

Comment: Перевожу текст ошибки на человеческий: nginx не знает, к какому DNS-серверу обратиться, чтобы по имени домена получить IP-адрес для подключения. DNS-сервер задаётся опцией [resolver](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)

Answer (score 0):

nginx.conf
resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8;

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]